# Creating Bernoulli random matrix using Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to implement compressed sensing in matlab, also trying different types of sensing matrix (Gaussian, Bernoulli, Fourier), and I have problems implementing -+1 Bernoulli random matrix as a sensing matrix, I am generating it as follows:

```
p=0.5;
A=(rand(M,256)<p);
A=A*2-1;
```

where M is

```
M => C*K*log(N/K)
```

N is the vector length, K is the non-zero coefficients, is that correct?

Comment: That gives a Mx256 matrix if i.i.d. Bernoulli variables with parameter `p` and values `+/-1`. If that's what you want, then it's correct